# Can table partitions exist on multiple servers?

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have a very large table that I need to establish table partitioning on.  Does SQL Server allow table partitions, for one table, to exist on multiple servers?

Example: my "Cars" table holds 300,000,000 rows.  I would like to store 100M of those rows on a hard drive located on Server1, 100M of those rows on Server2, and 100M of those rows on Server3.

Do the table partitions have to exist on the same server's hard drives (in the same server's file system)?

---

Environment: SQL Server 2016 Enterprise

Comment: Same instance -> table-> partitions -> different filegroups(each on different drive actual data - faster ones) or Stretch DB("hot data") on prem and "cold data" in Azure

Comment: Yes, they do need to be on the same server to be "a table"... but why would you want to do this, 300M rows isn't a lot.  If you have 3 good servers, build some form of H/A group with them to provide redundancy, or do merge replication on the data so its on all 3 servers simultaneously, and spread out the traffic if its crazy busy.  Don't fix a light bulb with a hammer.